# c++11 insert into collection with a lambda functional map

Tags: c++11, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming

It is kind of exasperating that `std` collections don't provide a functional map interface to fill a collection

```
std::vector< int > oldV = {1,3,5};
std::vector< int > newV = (oldV % [&](int v)-> int{ return v+1; });
newV.insert( oldV.begin(), oldV.end(), [&](int v)-> int{ return 2*v; });
```

Is there a simple header library that implements wrappers for functional style programming with `std` collections?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do it such that it would apply both to things like `std::vector` and `std::unordered_set` without repeating the operator definition for each container. In the case of vector it would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template <typename T, typename Lambda>
std::vector< T > operator |(const std::vector< T >& input, Lambda map)
{
        std::vector< T > output;
        for (const T& elem : input)
                output.push_back( map(elem) );
        return std::move(output);
};

int main()
{
        std::vector< int > oldV = {1,3,5};
        std::vector< int > newV = oldV | [&](int v) -> int { return v + 1; };
        for(int i=0; i< newV.size() ; i++)
        {
                std::cout << newV[i] << std::endl;
        }
};
```

For the case of `std::unordered_set` you would only have to replace `push_back` with `insert`

The [pipe operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Piping) here has the same well known semantics as on Unix/Linux shells and some languages

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::generate` and `std::transform` to do this.